# IE6 expressions: getting a parent element's height

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, expression

Let's say I have this markup:

```
<div class="foobar">
   <div style="height:expression(this.parent.style.height + 'px')"></div>
</div>
```

My expression doesn't work, but you can probably tell what I'm trying to do by it: get the height of the parent element.

Please, if you cannot answer the question do not bother replying. This is for a VERY, VERY specific bug that only affects IE. Either an expression must be used, or the bug cannot be fixed.

Comment: can you do an alert for `this.parent.style.height` and tell us what you're getting?

Comment: Also shouldn't `parent` be `parent()`

Comment: What is the "VERY, VERY specific bug"? There may be a better way to deal with it than using an expression.

Comment: @sAc no, because he isn't using a framework. Just standard javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="foobar">
   <div style="height:expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight + 'px')">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the height of the parent:

```
<div class="foobar">
   <div style="height:inherit;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will only work if the `height` has been explicitly set on `foobar`

Comment: @Scott: That is assumed pretty much here and footers do have a height in most cases :) Let's see what OP has to say.